# ARM-gcc stack usage files empty

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stack-overflow

I'm trying to analyze stack usage of my embedded program using arm-gcc toolchain. The program is single threaded so I normally can analyze the stack using the `-fstack-usage` gcc's parameter.

Normally this option generates `.su` files along with the compilation units. Those describe the stack usage per function. However in my case, those files are empty.

Here is an example of .su file content (from https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/08/21/gnu-static-stack-usage-analysis/):

```
main.c:36:6:bar    48    static
main.c:41:5:foo    88    static
main.c:47:5:main    8    static
```

I'm using `gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3` but the issue is also present on `gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_3-2016q1`.

Do you have an idea of the issue ? Or another solution to control the stack usage ?

Comment: Did you supply `-fstack-usage` option with your compilation command line (not linking line)? I tried this with gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2 and it works fine.

Comment: I give the parameter to both gcc (for compilation) and g++ (for linking). I'll try to switch to ld as linker.

Comment: Use gcc for linking instead of ld, it's advised this way.

Comment: Using gcc, g++ or ld give the same result. Here is the linker command (without the full list of files):
`arm-none-eabi-gcc -T gcc_arm.ld -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0  --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections,--print-gc-sections -fstack-usage`

Comment: I tried this and it worked (though failed in linking). Try to compile a single file and see if the *.su file is generated or not: `arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -o main main.c -fstack-usage`

Comment: Yep, compiling only a simple main.c produces the stack usage. I only had to add the `--specs=nosys.specs` parameter to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of tests I found a solution: `-fstack-usage` seems to be incompatible with `-flto`.

Disabling `-flto` allows to generate the .su files.

I don't really know the reason as I figured it out by enabling/disabling flags one by one. Also, by removing `-flto`, the linker fails but the stack usages are computed.

Comment: A belated follow-up to this question, but a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98922) was filed regarding this. The exact behaviour of the bug varies between gcc versions - and nobody there seems to have tested this with gcc 9 - but for versions 7 and 10 *temp files will reside in $TMPDIR and have
names like ccwn8X1t.ltrans0.ltrans.su*. For v11, the .su files at least have more predictable names and reasonable locations - see the link for more.

Comment: A belated follow-up to my previous belated follow-up - testing with 11.2 and `-flto` alongside `-fstack-usage`, FILENAME.out is accompanied by `FILENAME.out.ltrans0.ltrans.su` in the same directory (so not in `$TMPDIR`) in all three of the cases I've tried. In two of these cases (builds with `-O2` and `-O3` set) there was also a `FILENAME.out.ltrans1.ltrans.su` file. There wasn't one for my `-Os` build, and I don't think there was one for an earlier `-O2` build I did before this one.